# QGIS & WMS: Different aspect ratio between width/height and bbox

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms

I am experiencing a small screen space offset when using a WMS layer (origin is GeoServer 2.1.4). Looking at the requests from QGIS (1.7.4) to my GeoServer I realised that the aspect ratio between the `WIDTH/HEIGHT` and the `BBOX` is different. Calculating the aspect difference back into screen space gives a difference of ~1 pixel - I wonder if it could be the reason for my offset?

Due to devices with non-square pixels it makes sense that the aspect ratio can differ.

**But what is the reason for QGIS not enforcing equality between the aspect ratios?**

Comment: rounding error?

Comment: Where in the proces do you propose the *rounding error*?

Comment: probably in the bounding box as that is a floating point calculation as opposed to screen size (integer pixel count)?